# Vue/Nuxt JS No duplicate attribute

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I created  a header component with a navbar in Vue JS and I am getting a error message with Eslint:

```
Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-attribute-name. (vue/no-parsing-error)   13:14
Error   ESLint  Parsing error: duplicate-attribute. (vue/no-parsing-error)  13:14
Error   ESLint  Duplicate attribute 'to'. (vue/no-duplicate-attributes) 13:14
Error   ESLint  Parsing error: Unexpected closing tag "li". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags (prettier/prettier)
```

I am not sure how to fix this when they are just links, are we not allowed to have links on the same page with the same attributes and tags?

Here is the code:

```html
<template>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="title">Dad Jokes</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <nuxt-link to="/">Home</nuxt-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <nuxt-link to="/jokes">Jokes</nuxt-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <nuxt-link to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</template>
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Try deleting most of the code and reintroducing it a piece at a time to determine exactly what causes the problem. I suspect it'll be a rogue character, maybe an exotic white-space character or smart quotes.